# Outputdata in Excel not iterating properly in SpringBoot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-poi

So i am trying to read an excel file in springboot, the excel file contains 10 sheets, the code iterated all the sheets successfully but the row headers and cell data are not correct except for the first sheet ie the 2nd to last sheets are taking the first sheet information

Also the output are not well arranged, is there a way to make it clean

Below is the code

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("datafile")
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "getdata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void createBus() throws IOException {


        final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:\\project\\transita\\src\\main\\resources\\transita.xlsx";


        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook;

        {
            try {
                workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));



                // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
                System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");





                Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
                System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
                while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
                    System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());

                    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                    // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
                    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

                    // 1. You can obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
                    System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();

                        // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    try {
                        workbook.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Below is the output
1st sheet
=> partners

Iterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator

```
partner_id  partner_code    partner_name    partner_logo    partner_address partner_telephone   partner_email   partner_website External    Agency Oportunity   Search  sell    partner_id  
001 ABC ABC Transport       Km 5 MCC Uratta Rd, Owerri, Imo State -1111 2348139862090, 0700222872678    info@abctransport.com   https://www.abctransport.com    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A4  
002 CHT Chisco Transport Ltd        104, Funsho Williams Avenue, Iponri, Surulere, .    0816517669, 08089273799, 08113798985    Customercare@chiscogroupng.com  https://www.chiscotransport.com.ng  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A5  
003 LIB Libra Motors NIgeria Ltd        Cele Okota Road
Lagos Nigeria   09031565022 info@libmot.com www.libmot.com  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A6  
004 GIG GIGM Ltd        20 Ikorodu Express Road, Jibowu, Lagos.  08139851110    contact@gigm.com.   https://gigm.com/   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE       A7  
005 GUO GUO     Jibowu street along ikorodu express, Jibowu, Lagos. 2348144988273   info@guotransport.com   https://www.guotransport.com    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   A8
```

2nd sheet
=> p_policies

Iterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator

```
partner_id  partner_code    partner_name    partner_logo    partner_address partner_telephone   partner_email   partner_website External    Agency Oportunity   Search  sell    partner_id  
001 ABC ABC Transport       Km 5 MCC Uratta Rd, Owerri, Imo State -1111 2348139862090, 0700222872678    info@abctransport.com   https://www.abctransport.com    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A4  
002 CHT Chisco Transport Ltd        104, Funsho Williams Avenue, Iponri, Surulere.  0816517669, 08089273799, 08113798985    Customercare@chiscogroupng.com  https://www.chiscotransport.com.ng  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A5  
003 LIB Libra Motors NIgeria Ltd        Cele Okota Road
Lagos Nigeria   09031565022 info@libmot.com www.libmot.com  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A6  
004 GIG GIGM Ltd        20 Ikorodu Express Road, Jibowu, Lagos.  08139851110    contact@gigm.com.   https://gigm.com/   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE       A7  
005 GUO GUO     Jibowu street along ikorodu express, Jibowu, Lagos. 2348144988273   info@guotransport.com   https://www.guotransport.com    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   A8
```

3RD SHEET
=> schedules

Iterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator

```
partner_id  partner_code    partner_name    partner_logo    partner_address partner_telephone   partner_email   partner_website External    Agency Oportunity   Search  sell    partner_id  
001 ABC ABC Transport       Km 5 MCC Uratta Rd, Owerri, Imo State -1111 2348139862090, 0700222872678    info@abctransport.com   https://www.abctransport.com    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A4  
002 CHT Chisco Transport Ltd        104, Funsho Williams Avenue, Iponri, Surulere, L.   0816517669, 08089273799, 08113798985    Customercare@chiscogroupng.com  https://www.chiscotransport.com.ng  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A5  
003 LIB Libra Motors NIgeria Ltd        Cele Okota Road
Lagos Nigeria   09031565022 info@libmot.com www.libmot.com  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   A6  
004 GIG GIGM Ltd        20 Ikorodu Express Road, Jibowu, Lagos.  08139851110    contact@gigm.com.   https://gigm.com/   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE       A7  
005 GUO GUO     Jibowu street along ikorodu express, Jibowu, Lagos. 2348144988273   info@guotransport.com   https://www.guotransport.com    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   A8
```

Comment: You're always overriding the Sheet that the Iterator provides you with the Sheet at index zero. Remove "Sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)" and let only "Sheet sheet = Sheet Iterator.next()" defining your Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first portion of code you've posted, which is:

```
// ...other stuff...

Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
     Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
     System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());

     sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

     // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
     DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

// ...other stuff...
```

You're using the sheet iterator properly, retriving a new `Sheet` from the iterator at the beginning of your while using the following line:

```
Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
```

**But** then, mysteriously, *you're overriding the `Sheet` the iterator provides you with the `Sheet` at index zero (which is the first one of your `Workbook`*) with the indicted line of code:

```
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

So of course your while-loop is actually iterating through always *the first* `Sheet` of your `Workbook` (the `Sheet` at index zero). Remove that bad bad line and the problem is solved:

```
// ...other stuff...

Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
     Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
     System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());

     // sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); <-- BAD, BAD LINE!

     // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
     DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

// ...other stuff...
```